# ng build doesn't respect styles file order

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I recently updated to Angular 6, and noticed when I built my project with `ng build --prod`, my styles were messed up. In my angular.json, I have two files in styles:

```
"styles": [
    "src/assets/reset.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
```

No matter which order I have the two files in, the reset always ends up at the end of the compiled stylesheet, which screws up my styles. I can't figure out how to order the compiled sheet.

Comment: Hi, Did you tried importing it in your styles.scss file something like this
@import "assets/reset.css"

Comment: I know that's an option, but I posted the question as I was trying to find out how to make this functionality work again, as it did before angular 6, or if this is the new way it'll function and thus I need to do something else, like import (which feels like a work-around to the situation).